# Are there any non-real solutions of cot z = z?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I am trying to locate the solutions of $\cot z = z$. It is clear that there are an infinite number of solutions when $z$ is real just from looking at the graph, but how could I determine if there are any non-real complex roots? I tried letting $z=x+iy$ with $x,y $ both real and writing
$$ x+iy = \cot(x+iy) = \frac{\cos(x+iy) \sin(x-iy)}{\sin(x+iy)\sin(x-iy)} = \frac{\sin(2x)-i\sinh(2y)}{\cosh(2y)-\cos(2x)} $$
Equating real and imaginary parts gives two equations which must be satisfied:
$$ \frac{\sin(2x)}{\cosh(2y)-\cos(2x)}=x \;\; (1)\,, \hspace{1cm} \frac{\sinh(2y)}{\cosh(2y)-\cos(2x)} = -y \;\; (2)$$
If $y=0$ we recover the equation $\cot x = x$ and if $x=0$ we obtain $\coth y = -y$ which has no solutions (implying that there are no purely imaginary solutions) but I can't figure out how to deduce from these equations whether there are additional solutions for $x,y$ both non-zero. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y\neq 0$, equation $(2)$ can be rewritten as
$$
\cos(2x)=\cosh(2y)+\frac{\sinh(2y)}{y}>3,
$$
which cannot be satisfied for any $x\in\mathbb R$. Therefore, the system of equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ has no solution with $y\neq 0$.